# groovy NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, groovy, groovyshell

I am very new to groovy and I am trying out this example from the Groovy in Action book. I have this fibonacci.groovy program and when trying to run the program with java command, I am getting the NoClassDefFound error.

The command I am using in the console is:

```
java -cp %GROOVY_HOME%/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.0.jar;classes fibonacci
```

As you can see, I have mentioned the groovy-all jar in the classpath and I set the GROOVY_HOME variable. The classpath variable is not set, so I am assuming it has the default '.' value to find in the current folder itself. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you compiled `fibonacci.groovy` with groovyc? Does it tell you to go this route in the book? I assume `groovy fibonacci.groovy` works?

Comment: Yes I compiled it with groovyc and the classfiles have been generated fine. And yes, groovy fibonacci.groovy works

Comment: What is the actual full error message?

Comment: Here: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fibonacci
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fibonacci
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you missing the current folder in the classpath?

I'm on Linux, but if i compile a Groovy class with `groovyc` and then try to run it with `java`, i need to tell java where is my `groovy-all.jar` and also add the current dir to the classpath

So, this compilation works:

```
$ groovyc Fib.groovy
```

But this run doesn't runs:

```
$ java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.0.jar:classes Fib
```

As it's missing the current dir in the path:

```
$ java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.0.jar:. Fib
test for fib
```

---

Also note that if `fibonacci` is in a package, you need to type the full path to the class. So for this groovy source:

```
package up.foo
println "test for fib"
```

Compile:

```
$ groovyc Fib.groovy
```

We write the full package path to execute:

```
$ java -cp $GROOVY_HOME/embeddable/groovy-all-2.2.0.jar:. up.foo.Fib
```

There it is:

```
test for fib
```

Comment: Doesnt the default classpath '.' take the current folder into consideration? I am in the directory where this class is present when running this command. Will that not suffice?